# AWS Lightsail websites went down after adding a new Access Key, deleting earlier one

Tags: aws

From my AWS Security Credentials, I deleted an existing Access Key and created a new Access Key. Soon, I noticed that all my WordPress sites on Lightsail (Plesk Ubuntu Instance) are down, showing 500 Internal Error. Any help or clue how Lightsail instances are connected with Access Key will help update the relevant fields with the newly created Access Key.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Not sure the whole context of your case, maybe, you can try to snapshot your instances, and relaunch new instances with the snapshot together with the new access/secret keypair

Comment: The above problem was caused due to an internal problem with Plesk and had nothing to do with adding a new access key (coincidence).

Comment: oh sorry didnt help here

Answer (score 1):

The above problem was caused due to an internal problem with Plesk and had nothing to do with adding a new access key (coincidence).

[image]